# How do i print a string with repeated names followed by a number - Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

How do i print a name Ex. John1 and then print after John2, john3, john4, john5 and so one in an infinite number

I started using ruby today and I'm having some trouble figuring this out. I've searched some but can't find anything so how would I do this?

It's to mass produce accounts to the staff of a certain company and I found ruby to be the smartest to write it in and I will never use it again after this

Comment: String interpolation in a loop isn't *that* complex...

Comment: Please post a (code) snippet that didn't work for you.

Comment: @Makoto you also have to take into account the index. You don't want to add a separator after the last index. I can see how this would trip some people up. This is not that easy

Comment: If you want it infinitely this program will never finish, which is odd.

Comment: He obviously didn't mean infinitely. He clearly meant repeatedly. Read the question

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)”. "I found ruby to be the smartest to write it in and I will never use it again after this" doesn't do much to motivate potential answerers. We need to know what you tried, including the smallest code necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Or i could just close it with the X in the corner :D

Comment: But as Richard said, read the question :D

Comment: In other words, you're not willing to put in the effort to solve the problem, you want us to do it for you?

Comment: Put bluntly, the way you get something done in a language you're not willing to put time into, and that you never plan on using again, is you pay somebody to do it for you.  Or apparently, in your case, use SO as a free code-writing service.

Comment: Believe me ive tried, but the solution i came up with is not well the best.

Comment: First time on the forum, so thanks for the advice :D

Comment: @Odrai, why are you asking Frank for the code that didn't work for him? It may be that he doesn't know where to start, which would not be unusual for day 1 of learning a new language. If it's homework--and we don't know it is--SO rules expect him to report the efforts he has made to figure it out, but not necessarily to provide code. Also, ask yourself if you really want to embarrass him by forcing him to provide code that burns your eyes. As for SO being a free coding service (mentioned by others here and elsewhere) isn't that precisely what it is?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

```
puts (1..5).map { |n| "john#{n}" }
john1
john2
john3
john4
john5
```

The class [Range](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Range.html) `include`s the module [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html) (as does the classes `Array`, `Hash` and others). By doing so, instances of `Range` (such as `1..5`) gain the use of all of `Enumerable`'s instance methods. One of `Enumerable`'s instance methods is used here: [Enumerable#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

Answer (score 1):

For printing a simple series like this:

```
n = 1
loop do
  print 'john%d, ' % n
  n += 1
end
```

That will never terminate, which makes it kind of silly. Maybe what you want is a bounded range:

```
list = (1..10).map do |n|
   'john%d' % n
end.join(', ')

puts list
```

You can adjust the start and end values as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use an enumerator here:

```
enum = Enumerator.new do |y|
  i = 1
  loop do
   y << "John#{i}"
   i += 1
  end
end

enum.next #=> "John1"
enum.next #=> "John2"
enum.next #=> "John3"
```

Then use any one of the methods available to instances of [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-c-new). Here we've used [`Enumerator#next`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) to get the next "John" string.

Comment: Lazy enumerators are really the best way to generate a series like this. You could even write a function that returns one were you give it an arbitrary prefix.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the Lazy variety, so I would love to see an answer using said technique:)

Comment: You may be unfamiliar with the term, but you've built one here. What I mean by "lazy" is this Enumerator only generates values as they're requested by virtue of how `y` works. This is compared with an eager Enumerator that would generate a list in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is using a for loop. First declare an empty string variable that will hold our contents.

One important thing to consider is the index of the loop. If it's the last item, we do not want to add a separator like `", "`

This is where the conditional comes into play. If the index is less than the last, we will add a comma and space, otherwise just the name.

Interpolation is done by wrapping a variable inside `#{` and `}`

```
str = ""

for i in 1..5
  str += i < 5 ? "john#{i}, " : "john#{i}"
end
```

Returns

```
"john1, john2, john3, john4, john5"
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed it

Comment: `for` is hardly ever used in idiomatic Ruby code. It's almost always `(1..5).each ...` or some other iterator. Also try to avoid `+=` on strings, it creates tremendous amounts of garbage. `<<` is almost always preferable.

Comment: You're right, but `ruby` is the exception not the rule. Most languages use for loops, so I thought of that when answering the question.

Comment: @RichardHamilton - "Ruby is the exception not the rule. Most languages use for loops" - Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @BSeven Ruby is fairly unique in that it has hardly any use for the `for` construct. In most other languages this is an essential element. C, as just one example, leans heavily on it, and many other languages are inspired by C in at least some capacity.

Comment: @tadman - I mentioned it because I wondered if more modern and higher level languages (including Javascript) are moving away from for loops and towards `map` and `each`.

Comment: JavaScript is being influenced by Ruby here, things like Lodash/Underscore owe a lot to Ruby's Enumerable library. Using iterator functions gives more flexibility, the body of the loop is re-usable for example, or can be specified dynamically, and in some cases performance is actually faster. You're right, the old stalwart `for` might be losing ground.